# How do I update underlying list when calling BindingSource.RemoveCurrent

Tags: c#, winforms, bindingsource

I have the following simple class;

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

List<MyObject> oList = new List<MyObject>();
```

My list is populated with some items.  I then populate my BindingSource with the list like;

```
MyBindingSource.DataSource = oList; //contains some items in a list
```

My BindingSource is linked to a DataGridView (which doesn't really matter in this example), but depending on the selected row in the DataGridView, I then have the following method for my datagrid view clicked button;

```
private void MyDataGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == btnRemove.Index)
    {
        MyBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
    }
}
```

The call

> MyBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()

removes the items from the DataGridView, but how do I remove the item from the underlying list which is oList.

I thought that assigning **MyBindingSource.DataSource** = oList, means the list shown in **MyBindingSource.DataSource** is actually pointing to oList ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<T>` isn't smart enough to know things have changed, so try using a `BindingList<T>` from System.ComponentModel instead:

```
BindingList<MyObject> oList = new BindingList<MyObject>();
```

Comment: If I'm dealing with BindingSource, DataGrid and data aware controls, should all my lists be BindingList ? Or only when they need to be 'data aware' like my issue above.

Comment: @Tommo1977 For the most part, yes, if you need that *feedback*, I would use the BindingList<T>.  BindingList<T> also has a ListChanged event, which is helpful sometimes, too.